# Does a rotating button magnet result in a changing magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

A button magnet, with sides facing outwards, taking N to be facing out of the page would have a constant magnetic field pointing into the page. By rotating it, it appears like the magnetic field would stay constant due to the rotational symmetry of the button magnet. However, does the magnetic field really stay constant when being rotated?

Comment: You should really specify how you are rotating it, I'm assuming you mean rotation around the axis of the two faces since you state the magnetic field of the rotating magnet has symmetry.